# Select book titles having read by more than 10 people

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables as follows.

person(**pid**, name)
book(**isbn**, title)
read(**pid**, **isbn**)

How do i Select book titles having read by more than 10 people

Comment: Check out GROUP BY combined with HAVING, and count().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you simply want a list of these books then you can do something like this. I've changed the result to greater than 5 so there's not a stupid amount of sample data.

This will count unique readers of each book rather than total reads (in case somebody has read the book more than once).

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #Read (pid int, isbn int)
INSERT INTO #Read (pid, isbn)
VALUES
(1,1324)
,(2,1324)
,(3,1324)
,(4,1324)
,(5,1324)
,(6,1324)
,(1,5678)
,(2,5678)
```

Query

```
SELECT
    r.isbn
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT r.pid) Readers
FROM #Read r
GROUP BY r.isbn
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.pid)  > 5
```

Result

```
isbn    Readers
1324    6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select isbn, count(*) from read
group by isbn
having count(*) > 10
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the ISBN number is the unique identifier for the book (as it is in real life) not the pid (which appears to be the person id). Also, what if the same person has read the book more than once?

Comment: You're right, should be on isbn. For one person having read a book more than once, that's unclear from the question. I'd assume grouping on both isbn and pid should fix that.